# use useState hook, however the setter function is undefined at runtime

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am using `useState` hook in my react-native project. I have a screen which renders my custom component named `MyComponent`. The setter function of state is called in `MyComponent` 's `onSelected` callback.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent'

const MyScreen=()=> {
  ...
  const {parts, setParts} = useState(initialParts);

  return (<View>
           <MyComponent onSelected={()=> {
                                 ...
                                 setParts(newParts)
                                   }}/>
        </View>)
}
...
```

`MyComponent` looks like this, in the `onPress` callback of `TouchableOpacity`, it calls the passed in `onSelected` function:

```
const MyComponent= ({onSelected})=> {
  ...
  return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
                                      onSelected();
                                      ...
                                      }}>
           ...
          </TouchableOpacity>)
 }
```

When I run my app on iOS emulator, the screen shows, when I tap on MyComponent, I get error `TypeError: setParts is not a function. (In setParts(newParts)), 'setParts' is undefined`.

Why I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your destructuring here seems wrong:

```
  const {parts, setParts} = useState(initialParts);
```

Shouldn't be this:

```
  const [parts, setParts] = useState(initialParts);
```

?

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm, it seems like you have to read the React official documentation to know more about UseState.

here is fix to your code:

```
const MyScreen = () => {
  const [parts, setParts] = useState(initialParts) // see this fix.

  return (
    <View>
      <MyComponent
        onSelected={() => {
          setParts(newParts)
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

basically, it is in the form of `array` de-structuring instead of `object` like you wrote above.

learn more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html